# How can use Two roles in attribute role

Tags: angular, permissions, roles, assign, multiple-instances

I have a problem with the insertion of two roles in the directive [role]
Code HTML

```
<app-authorize-veiw [role]="'Admin'">
  <ng-container Authorized>
<a [routerLink]="['/DemandeConges',row.id]">
  <button mat-icon-button  >
  <mat-icon color="secondary">visibility</mat-icon>
</button>
</a>
  </ng-container>
</app-authorize-veiw>
```

code html of app-authorize-view>

```
<ng-content *ngIf="!isAuthorized()" select ="[notAuthorized]"></ng-content>
<ng-content *ngIf="isAuthorized()" select ="[Authorized]"></ng-content>
```

Ts file

```
export class AuthorizeVeiwComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private securityService:SecurityService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


 @Input()
  role: string='';
public isAuthorized(){

  if(this.role){
return this.securityService.getRole() === this.role;

  }else {
    return this.securityService.isAuthenticated();
  }
```

please someone help me

Comment: Could you show us how `app-authorize-view` is implemented? My guess is that `[row]` is an `@Input` of the `app-authorize-view` component, and it's not a directive.

Comment: i add code of app-authorize-view @skouch2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accept more than one roles, you will need to update your code. These changes include:

1. `@Input row` input.
2. `isAuthorized()` function.

---

First, you will need to update your input to accept array of string instead of a string.

Then in the `isAuthorized` function, you need to loop through the `requiredRoles` to check if the `currentRole` from the `securityService`'s role matches any of the supplied `requiredRoles`.

##### authorizeView.component.ts

```js
export class AuthorizeViewComponent {

  ...

  // update to array string to accept more than one roles.
  @Input()
  public requiredRoles: string[] = []; 

  constructor(private securityService: SecurityService) { }

  public isAuthorized(){

    if(this.requiredRoles.length === 0)
      return this.securityService.isAuthenticated();

    const currentRole = this.securityService.getRole();

    // currentRole has to match at least one of the required roles to be true.
    const hasRequiredRole = this.requiredRoles
      .some(role => currentRole === role);

    return hasRequiredRole;
  }

  ...

}
```

##### example.component.html

```html
...

<app-authorize-veiw [requiredRoles]="myRoles">
  <ng-container Authorized>
    <h2> You are Authorized! </h2>
  </ng-container>
</app-authorize-veiw>

...
```

##### example.component.ts

```js
export class ExampleComponent {

  ...

  public myRoles = ['Admin', 'Student'];

  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you sir for your help it is a code that works well

Comment: @salahkimi Please accept this answer by clicking on the Check so that other don't try to answer this again in the future.

Comment: i accept it thinks again